# Set-Cookie cached , even with F5 ? (unless I press CTRL+F5)

Tags: php, caching, cookies

I obviously see, that in specific cases, after `SetCookie()` function, when I reload the page (or re-enter that page), I don't see the cookies set, unless i press `CTRL+F5` (which is cache-cleared request).
have you ever met such occasion (this happens only on `http` version of the file, not on `https`).

this didn't help:

```
header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

What I should do in order to get cookies read on next page-enter?

Comment: Is there any specific way you can reproduce this or is it just random?

Comment: @apokryfos very hard for me to explain... it happens on specific VPS installation  on a specific page if requested with `http` (this doesnt happen on `https` )

Comment: Check the developer console (i.e. F12 if using chrome). See what cookies are being set and if the correct headers are there. I recently had a headache with cookies being set under the wrong path.

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for that, nice tip. however, that shows same as `var_dump($_COOKIE)`.  Well, i have never met this before myself,and only i might find out the issue... btw, post your comment as answer, really worth to upvote.

Comment: Explain what exactly _“I don't see the cookies set”_ means - _where_ don’t you see them? If you are relying on output of $_COOKIE, then this is how it is supposed to work - $_COOKIE is only populated with the cookies send back by the client on the _next_ request, it does not get updated while your script instance which is _setting_ the cookies is running.

Comment: @misorude You should have thought, that I do know that already, you shouldnt concentrate on that. When i said, it is not set, i even wrote that on "next-entry" on that page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies generally are hard to debug when they go wrong. What you are describing does seem to be related to caching but it sounds very odd.

Here's what you can try doing to see what's wrong.

1. Make sure you are setting the cookie in the correct domain and path . If your page is e.g. at `www.example.com` the domain should either be `.example.com` or `www.example.com`. The idea is same for the path (if you access `www.exampl.com/path` then the path needs to either be `/` or `/path`
2. If you need the cookie to be available on http then you should not set the `secure` attribute on it.
3. Make sure the cookie is not already expired when set, browsers will probably ignore it if it is.

A few basic things to check.

Assume that you have cookie line:

```
setcookie('name', 'value', time()+10000,'/test','.example.com');
```

Open the Chrome (or your favourite browser's) developer console and when you make the request check the cookies being set. There should be something along the lines of:

[image]

The duration must not be 0 and the rest should be correct.

When you make the next request the cookie should be sent as well.

[image]

This should be an entry in the "Request cookies".

If the cookie is received, but then not sent to the server it might be worth opening the browser settings and finding the stored cookies manually for any hints as to why this is happening. In chrome this would be in `chrome://settings/siteData`

If you still don't find anything wrong with any of these then check if there's any intermediate caching layer running, that would override the `No-Cache` header you are setting.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that there was some kind on Nginx caching enabled, causing the browser not to recall the execution from server. 
I've fixed that by including the `random()` string in the url, voiding the cache for that page-call.